# Why does new String("") compile while char c = '' does not?

Tags: java

Why are empty Strings valid and empty chars are not ?
I would have thought an empty String is not a string but just a placeholder. The same for a char, but creating an empty char does not even compile.

What im wondering is why the following occurs - 
Compiles -

```
String s = "";
```

Does not compile -

```
char c = '';
```

Comment: What value would you expect `c` to have if your example did compile?

Comment: Would not have expected it to have any value.

Comment: Well, it turns out that you cannot have a `char` that does not have a value. A `char`, like an `int` or `double` must have *some* value at all times.

Comment: You could set a `Character` to null if you need a special 'no character' value.

Comment: isn't ASCII 0 the NUL character?  That's what I would expect.

Comment: Java is not C++; don't initialize strings to new String("").  That causes 2x strings to be created.  Instead, initialize them to "" if you want an empty string (ex. String example = "").

Comment: NUL is 0x00.  '' is not equal to 0x00.  if you want to set a char to NUL, do this: char c = 0x00;

Comment: Or ASCII 0 can be represented as `'\0'`.

Comment: Or use `char? c = null;`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Because `char` represents a single character, which `''` isn't. A String can contain zero or more characters, but a character cannot be anything other than a single character.

Comment: Yes, it would be like setting an integer to .. nothing.

Comment: Actually, I had assumed that the compiler would initialise the variable to (literally) 0 which would be no character in any encoding. I thought...

Comment: @Andrew: Character 0 is a character. Specifically, it is known as `NUL` or `'\0'`.

Comment: It has to do with the C parser. The parser expects one "'", one character (or a backslash followed by an escaped character), and one "'".

Comment: Isn't it technically the case that "" as an empty string is really a not-very-large part of the heap which the actual variable points to while the actual variable obviously contains a non-zero value, namely the address of the first byte of the (empty) string?

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying Andrew, but when you do `char * string = "";` the pointer points to a string literal thats not in the heap or the stack, but in the actual program instructions/data. Whether java does this exact thing, I am not sure.

Comment: Makes sense completely. Nice.. +1

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm: Certainly, the language designers could have made `''` equivalent to `'\0'`, but they chose not to, probably because that would lead to a small but steady trickle of SO questions along the lines of, "What does `''` mean in Java?"

Answer (score 34):

Because a string literal represents a String which may consist of **zero or more** characters, but a (valid) character literal represents **exactly one** character.

---

> A char could be defined as a datatype that can store 0 or 1 characters ...

Yes.  In theory it could have been defined that way.  But trust me, if you think through **all** the issues (e.g. how you'd represent an empty char, how an application would deal with it, etc) you will conclude that the there are few benefits, and significant downsides.

Anyway, doing this *merely* so that there was a syntactic consistency between String and char literals would be totally crazy.  You don't break a language's performance and/or semantics so that the syntax looks nice.

---

One comments on the accepted answer proposes that `''` should mean the same as `'\0'`.  But the counter argument to this is that `'\0'` does not mean no characters.  It means one character whose value is zero.  So if `''` *actually* means one character it is misleading.  And since there is already a way of denoting this ... `'\0'` ... a second way of denoting it is redundant.

If some piece of new language syntax is both misleading and redundant, it is hard to justify adding it.

In respose to SoloBold's comment, while it would be possible to define a character type to do that, it would require more space.  At least 1 bit, and more likely 16 bits to avoid awkward memory alignment problems.  A 32-bit `char` type would not be acceptable ... even though it does solve other problems.

Comment: In other words, its a design/definition decision.  A `char` could be defined as a datatype that can store 0 or 1 characters, but it is not defined that way.  Which is probably good, since an empty `char` is pretty useless.

Comment: @wprl - A more practical reason why it is a bad idea is that would entail either "stealing" a `char` value to represent the "no character" case, or making `char` bigger to make space for a flag to denote "no character".

Answer (score 13):

`""` is an empty array of characters.

`''` is simply not a character.

Answer (score 8):

An empty string is like a container that holds nothing. A `char` must have a value and without exactly one character there is no where to derive that value from.

Answer (score 5):

You could see a String as a sequence of characters. Having an empty sequence with no characters makes sense, having a character that isn't a character doesn't.

Also never use `String s = new String("");`, just `String s = ""` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically, an alphabet A is a set of symbols, suppose alphabet A = {a, b, c, d, ..., z}. A string L is a sequence of zero or more characters from an alphabet, i.e. L = A*. An empty string is simply a sequence of zero characters; while an "empty chars" is not a member of the alphabet.

You can't have an empty character, it is illogical.

Answer (score 4):

char is a primitive type, so you need to give a value (whatever it is).
If you want to leave you variable as "undefined", you can use the wrapper object:

```
Character c = null;
```

In this way you variable c is not containing (yet) any value. But then be sure to add a value! :)

Answer (score 2):

By the way, you can use the object wrapper for primitive `char` type:

```
Character c = null;
Character c2 = 'a';
```

This can be useful when you want a field to be "either a character or nothing".

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = null;              // OK
String s = new String("");    // OK
String s = new String("A");   // OK
String s = new String("ABC"); // OK

char c = 'A';                     // OK
char c = '';                      // NOT OK!
Character c = null;               // OK
Character c = new Character('A'); // OK
Character c = new Character('');  // NOT OK!
```

Comment: as noted by others, the `new` keyword is unnecessary here, actually causing 2 objects to be created in each case; one for the `"A"` part and one for the `new` part (based on/copied from `"A"`)...

Comment: I used new String() to make it look the same as new Character() and to make it explicit that Character is an object while char is not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because char is a primitive type, and String is an object. 
boolean, int etc. also don´t allow "empty" values.

Answer (score 0):

A char is a single character, that is a letter, a digit, a punctuation mark, a tab, a space or something similar.

Comment: ASCII 0 is NUL, a single character.  And it does exist, as the terminator in a NULL terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

String is a set of characters which could be 0 or more. so empty strings are valid- which dont have any character. BUt char represents the primitive type of Character which has to be one valid character, which '' is not.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to know the difference between blank character/string and empty character/string. blank char/string refers to character/string that has some content, such as ' '(SPACE), '\t' and so on, while empty ones doesn't have any content, and can be seen as an empty container.